# The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting the following error for the last line of my Apps Script code - “ Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues. (line 52, file "TaskCompletionDate")”

The code picks up the spreadsheet range using sheet.getDataRange() and based on certain conditions, picks values from this range to a column array called Col8.
After the array Col8 is completely written, I paste this Col8 into my spreadsheet. The error refers to this step.

Shortened version of my code is as follows:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet_ID");
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet_name"); 

var rows = sheet.getLastRow();  
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
var Col8 = new Array(rows-1,1);

for (var i=2; i<=rows; i++)
    {
          if (values[i-1][1] == "Completed") 
         {
           if (!values[i-1][8]) 
           Col8[i-1][1].setValue(values[i-1][1]);        
          }
      }

  sheet.getRange(2,8,rows-1,1).setValues(Col8);
```

[Spreadsheet columns can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0D7b.png)

[image]

What am I missing?
I am not a programmer, nor do I know JavaScript or Apps Script, but have been building small Apps Script snippets using the App Script documentation and other app script resources on the net.

Comment: I'd be happy to assist.  If you could provide an image of the sheet involved in your question it would be helpful. Please insure that the image show the rows and columns and column titles.

Comment: The reason for the error is that your variable Col8 needs to be a 2 dimensional array and it's not.  I can help you fix that with an image of your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic starting point. But I need information from your spreadsheet image in order to make sure the indices are correct.  I noticed that you create today and yesterday but you don't actually use them.

```
function myfunvtion() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet_ID");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet_name"); 
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vs=rg.getValues();
  var today=new Date();
  var yesterday=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-1);
  var oA=[];
  for (var i=0; i<vs.length;; i++) {
    if (values[i][1]=="Completed" && !values[i][18]) {
      oA.push([vs[i][1]]);//it looks like your fixing something in your spreads        
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2,8,oA.length,1).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Here's the link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z0h93kftpBtJ1XVZxa0NU2m-VmuKbWypVW8rGd5KKDw/edit?usp=sharing

Today & Yesterday are unused because I forgot to take them off while posting the shortened version of my code in stackoverflow!

Comment: I'd prefer an image posted in your question.

Comment: Image posted. I get that I did not declare the 2 dimension array correctly. 

The code you have provided works fine for me. I can adapt it to my exact need. 
The only thing I need help with now is  - Pushing a null value to oA. 
How to do that?
I will push a null value to oA when the if condition is not met.

Comment: Well I guess `vs[i][1]='';oA.push([vs[i][1]]);`